# vue mutation push object reference?

Tags: web, vue.js, frontend, vuex

```
addSentence: (state) => {
  const obj = state;
  // next line is correct;
  obj.sentences.push({ ...obj.current });
  // change to next line, get error 
  // obj.sentences.push(obj.current);
  obj.current = new Sentence();
},



import Constants from './Constants';

export default class Sentence {
  constructor(config) {
    this.text = '';
    this.fontFamily = 'KaiTi';
    this.fontSize = 16;
    this.fontStyle = '';
    this.appearStyle = {
      name: 'type',
      speed: 40,
      startDelay: 0,
    };
    this.disappearStyle = {
      name: 'backspace',
      speed: 80,
      startDelay: 0,
      smartBackspace: true,
    };

  }

  play(context) {

  }

  drawText() {

  }

}
```

state.cuurent is an object of type Sentence.
And state.sentences = [Sentence]

This is a mutation handler.

Error:
[vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.

Comment: if that `addSentence` isn't a commit, then that's where the error is. Hard to know without more context

Comment: This line of code is defintely the source of error..

Comment: if you want to mutate, you should have been calling something like `this.$store.commit("addSentence")` if you're doing anything but, you'll receive this error.

Comment: I'm exactly doing what you said..and I got that error.

Comment: Why do you create obj variable? `const obj = state;`
It would be better if you add jsfiddle demo.

Comment: can I nest objects in state?

Comment: you can nest objects and do whatever you want to - `state` is  just a `vuex` object - think of it as a container that can hold the things that you ask to hold, however any change (mutation) to it  is always done using mutation. use `commit` to set/change the state of the objects held by the vuex state